# No entiendo por qué console.log(Number.parseInt('F', 16)) da como resultado 15 en hex

Tags: javascript

Si reemplazo la letra "F" por cualquier otra, ¿qué resultado dará?

Comment: Porque ese es el valor de `F` en hex.

Answer (score 7):

El segundo parámetro de [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt) es la `base`. Vos estás definiendo una base 16, hexadecimal.

En hexadecimal los valores van de `0 - 9` y de `A - F`, lo que da un total de 16 valores.

`F` es el último valor, por eso vale 15 (0 es el primero, por eso 16 valores).

```js
console.log(Number.parseInt(0, 16));
console.log(Number.parseInt(1, 16));
console.log(Number.parseInt(2, 16));
console.log(Number.parseInt(3, 16));
console.log(Number.parseInt(4, 16));
console.log(Number.parseInt(5, 16));
console.log(Number.parseInt(6, 16));
console.log(Number.parseInt(7, 16));
console.log(Number.parseInt(8, 16));
console.log(Number.parseInt(9, 16));
console.log(Number.parseInt('A', 16));
console.log(Number.parseInt('B', 16));
console.log(Number.parseInt('C', 16));
console.log(Number.parseInt('D', 16));
console.log(Number.parseInt('E', 16));
console.log(Number.parseInt('F', 16));

console.log(Number.parseInt('G', 16));
```

Si usas una letra que está por fuera del rango `A - F`, te va a devolver [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NaN) (Not a Number).

Comment: +10 por el NaN ( que siempre me recuerda a https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnfJU7w9ohQ )